# Confused about getting the index from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array with some text:

```
var values = ['text1', text2',...]
```

This array fills a select with the text and when the user selects an option, creates an ul list with the value and another array with all the options the user has selected. What I want is to let the user delete that element from the list and from the array, the problem is when I try to get the index of the li selected

```
//Here it appends the element selected to the list
$('#container ul#header').append('<li class="list-group-item">'  +  text + '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></span> </li>');


 function deleteElement(){
    $(".list-group-item span").click(function(){
       var index = values.indexOf( $(this).parent().text() )
   });
 }
```

But it always return -1, but when I hardcode the element text I want to delete it does find it

```
values.indexOf( $(this).parent().text() ) //Doesnt work
values.indexOf( 'text1' ) //This works
```

EDIT:

$(this).parent().text() returns the text from the li

On the console thats what it shows, but when I console the length of the string, it returns the size plus one:

```
//String
values.indexOf( $(this).parent().text().length ); //7
values.indexOf( 'string'.length ); //6
```

So I guess it has to do with this, I'm trying to figure why it returns plus one, I gues it has to do with the , I'm not sure.

Comment: what dose $(this).parent().text() returns??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `trim()` the `text()` due to the whitespace after the `</span>`:

```
var index = values.indexOf($(this).parent().text().trim());
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/b7z51hoh/)

Comment: Yeah, it was that, when I console the length it showed string plus one, the span, well now I feel dumb haha